# How do I create a file from a result set?

Tags: oracle

I'm using Oracle 11g (I think)

I'm trying to create a flat file (CSV or TXT) from a result set but am struggling on where to even start. It seems like I have to create a stored proc and use `UTL_FILE`. After doing some research, I have two questions:

1. Where does the file get created? According to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/88740/how-to-create-script-file-with-pl-sql) I need to get access to the Oracle user directory, but where is that on a Windows and Linux environment? I have to test on Windows , and the script will eventually be on a Linux environment.
2. What would be the basic format of a SQL script to create the aforementioned file, and load data into it from a fairly basic `SELECT` query?

Answer (score 0):

There's two routes to go through.

Firstly, Server-side. This is where a process on the machine hosting the DB will write the data to its file system using UTL_FILE. A DIRECTORY entry needs to be created in the database by a DBA pointing to a directory on the file system which can be written to by the OS process running the database (generally 'oracle')

Secondly, client-side. This is where a client program (eg SQL*Plus, Java, Python, Excel...) connects to the database, pulls the required data across to the client and writes it to a file on the client's file system.

You can have the client and server on the same machine, or a shared directory/file system that is accessible to both a client and server (one side needs to be able to read/write, the other can just be read).

You need to decide which best fits your situation, including

- where you want the file to end up
- whether the task will be invoked manually or through a scheduler/automation
- how to manage and deploy changes to the script/code that generates the file

Comment: If you go for the client side, the new JAVA based [SQLcl](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/overview/index.html) might be an option. It can generate CSV, JSON and other output directly.